# Difference between apache.avro and spark-avro from databricks

Tags: apache-spark

I am new in spark, want to work on avro files, but i am not getting which library i should you use, org.apache.avro or spark-avro from databricks, i am not getting what is the actual difference between this.

Answer (score 2):

Before Spark 2.4 there was no official Spark support for Avro, and so anyone wanting to use Avro in Spark had to use the Databricks library. With the release of Spark 2.4, the Databricks library has been migrated into Spark, and the Databricks library is now archived.

So if you're using Spark 2.4 you should use the built-in version of Avro, but for earlier versions of Spark you'll need to use the Databricks version.

Sources:

- The [Databricks spark-avro GitHub project](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) says:

  > Databricks has donated this library to the Apache Spark project, as of Spark 2.4.0
- The [Databricks blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/30/apache-avro-as-a-built-in-data-source-in-apache-spark-2-4.html) explaining the migration into Spark 2.4